# How do you prevent Visual Studio from switching to the Code Analysis tab after each build?

Tags: code-analysis, visual-studio-2012

After each build, Visual Studio 2012 switches from the Solution Explorer to the Code Analysis tab, usually with the yellow "No code analysis issues were detected." (Might as well say "TA DA!").

Is there an option to turn off the tab switching (keeping it on Solution Explorer)? [because I can't find it either in Solutions or Options].

Thanks!

Comment: I think this will help you : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193260.aspx

Comment: Milad: That only turns it off. Like an oil-low-light in a car, I prefer it working... just not taking over the whole display.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**VS 2012**

The best answer I have found so far is to drag the Code Analysis view's tab away from the Solution explorer. I've docked mine below the Solution explorer and made it about 1 inch high - so I can still see what it is reporting on the rare occasions when I wish to check it, but without losing my Solution Explorer all the time.

It's still unnecessary but a lot less irritating.

---

**Update - VS 2013**

In VS 2013 you can now click the **Settings** option in the Code Analysis view, and disable the `Show window when issues are detected` option.

Answer (score 16):

Right Click Project --> Properties --> Code Analysis Tab --> Uncheck Enable Code Analysis on Build.

Hope that Helps.

Comment: The question is how to make VS2012 quit stealing focus, not how to stop code analysis completely.  Your solution works, but it is too extreme for what I want.

Comment: You can run code analysis manually, or setup a build type with it enabled and have it off normally. I'd prefer the old way, but this works for me.

Comment: Found the same [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e05a02t4(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Just found very helpful blog post about your issue [Temporarily disable the C# static code analysis for a whole VS instance](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2013/03/30/VS2012-Temporarily-disable-the-C-static-code-analysis-for-a-whole-VS-instance.aspx).

Also I have found way to permanently disable Code Analysis for all VS 2012 instances:
You need to add Windows environment variable with name "DevDivCodeAnalysisRunType" and value "Disabled" (all without quotes). There is helpful post about Windows environment variables [How To Add/Edit Environment Variables in Windows 7](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/).

Hope that helps.