# Disable Code Analysis in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you prevent Visual Studio from switching to the Code Analysis tab after each build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199625/how-do-you-prevent-visual-studio-from-switching-to-the-code-analysis-tab-after-e)

im now using Visual Studio 2012, the RTM version.

every time i build, i get the code analysis tab opening showing code hints. Its slowing down my compile times.

Ive spent time googleing it, but as its 2012 there are not much help online yet.

Does anyone know how can i disable it?

Comment: If you haven't found out how to disable it, how do you know that it's slowing down your build?

Comment: because it loads the analysis every build, plus it feels slower as I've just migrated from 2010 - also it pops up over the solution explorer which is really annoying

Comment: @GregHewgill In VS 2010, code analysis took place, but it was in a different window.  However, this new window seems to take bit longer to render, but has the annoying property of always being switched to when the build is performed.  Turning off code analysis for the project makes it faster, but in general, the code feature is slower than in VS 2010.

Comment: @casperOne - You marked this as a dup, but doesn't link to the dup!?!  And please don't tell me to search, since searching got me here to begin with.  (Seems like a flaw in the API that the 'marked as dup' feature doesn't require the "original" question.)

Comment: @Mike Did you see the "Possible duplicate" banner at the top?  There's a link there to the question it's a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see it at the time. I've run into enough of these now that I finally noticed it in another post. I still feel some of my original statement stands, there seems to be a flaw in the site design. The thing about this and similar posts is that, what draws my eye is the big 'marked as duplicate' area below the question. A secondary flaw to mention is that the duplicates seem to get more comments or somehow otherwise end up at the top of searches. (FYI, I normally get to SO via an MSDN search. - http://mycroftproject.com/updateos.php/id0/msdn-libso.xml)

Answer (score 8):

Double click the properties folder in solution explorer. There should be a code analysis tab. From there you can enable or disable code analysis.

Comment: Enable Code Analysis was unticked, every build now it comes up saying - CA0063 Issue Running Code Analysis

Comment: Why doesn't this article say that... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175(v=vs.110).aspx crazy!

Comment: thanks! I might to set project to project in Properties, and unckeck the "enable code anlysis" and it works.

Comment: Just to clarify - you should go to the project's properties, not the solution's properties (which also has a code analysis options)